# 'std::string' has no member named 'username' error

Tags: c++, class, stdstring

My code won't compile because of a 'std::string' has no member named 'username' error. I'm using code::blocks. I'm guessing the problem is because I'm trying to assign a string to a class, can someone help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class userx
{
public:
    string username;
    string password;
};

int main()
{
    userx X, Y;

    X.username = "X";
    X.password = "1234";
    Y.username = "Y";
    Y.password = "5678";

    string a;
    string b;

    cout << "What is your name?" << endl;
    cin >> a;

    if (a.username == a)
    {
        cout << "What is your password?" << endl;
        cin >> b
        if (a.password == b)
        {
            cout << "Password Accepted" << endl;
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: This bug would probably be avoided if you used proper variable names. X, Y, a and b tell you exactly nothing about what the variables represent.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote `a.username` when you probably meant `X.username` or `Y.username`.

Comment: the idea is that you would provide a value for a, and if that value was X or Y, a.username would become X.username or Y.username. I accept that this is probably syntactically rubbish, can you think of a way round it?

Answer (score 2):

```
if(a.username == a)
```

since `a` is `string` so it doesn't have username as its member that can be accessible using dot operator

Answer (score 0):

Your code says

```
if(a.username == a){
cout<<"What is your password?"<<endl;
cin>>b
if(a.password = b){
cout<<"Password Accepted"<<endl;
};
```

when you declared `string a;` And indeed a `std::string` has no `username`.

Perhaps you meant to compare what was entered with X:

```
if(X.username == a){
  cout<<"What is your password?"<<endl;
cin>>b
if(X.password = b){
  cout<<"Password Accepted"<<endl;
};
```

Maybe you also mean to check against `Y`.
You might want to think about what happens if if the `username` is wrong. As it stands it will say password accepted even if the username is wrong.

**Edit**
In fact `if(X.password = b)` is an assignment not a comparison, so your user will probably get through regardless of username and password.

**Edit again**
It sounds like what you want is to use `std::find` on a container or to see if a `std::map` contains a given key using its `find` method. There are plenty of [online clues](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find)

Comment: Not to mention `=` and `==`

Comment: @Angew I knew they'd be many more things in there - good spot.

Comment: Yeah, I put this up in a bit of a rush, trying to re-create the same code I had running the other day. Its not really what I was looking at . The second if statement might as well be pseudo code at this stage.

Comment: I don't want to hard code the if statements for X and Y. I want the code to apply for any number of cases, ie. userx X,Y,Z,A,B,C,D... etc. The idea is you would type in a value for a (eg. ABC) which would look for userx ABC (if it exists), with a.username becoming ABC.username.

Comment: for(auto item & user : users ) { ... } or use a `std::map` of usernames to passwords and see if the username is in there and if the value matches the given pwd?

Comment: The map function looks promising. I don't really get the syntax of that for expression though. How does that work? - I'm fairly new to C++.

Comment: It's a data structure note a function. Start by read "Accelerated C++: Practical Programming by Example" by Koenig and Moo